# Hook-length formula

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups, characters, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ be a partition of $d$. Then hook length formula gives us

$$dim(\lambda)=\chi_{1^d}^{\lambda}=\frac{d!}{\prod h_{\lambda}(i,j)}$$
where $\chi_{a}^{b}$ denote the character of symmetric group.

Say $d$ is even,does there exists hook-length formula for all $\lambda$
$$\chi_{2^{d/2}}^{\lambda}? $$

Comment: what does $\chi_a^b$ mean ?

Comment: Character of symmetric group.

Comment: but characters are not integers.

Comment: So what it has to do with my question?

Comment: There is some machinery in the [hook-length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) that you are skipping over.  One associates to integer partition $\lambda$ of $d$ a complex irreducible representation $V_\lambda$, and $\dim \lambda$ is then understood as an abbreviated form of $\dim V_\lambda$.